# Input layer in Neural Network with different vocabulary size

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to build a Neural Network where each neuron in the input layer will have different size. For instance, x1 = [0 1 0], x2 = [13 4 5 1 9 0], x3 = 7...
Would it be possible to train this model? What should I change from a normal size neural network? Would it be better fill with zeros to the maximum size?

Comment: Take a look at recurrent neural networks, they handle variable sized inputs naturally.

Comment: RNN are suitable for sequences, but my samples are independent. In addition, it is good for the community knowing if a simple NN could handle variable sized inputs. Thanks

Comment: this question is badly specified. you don't specify what the inputs mean- does 4 in x2 correspond to 1 in x1 ( ie same dimension)... and the vector mapping is not unique to neural networks its common to most ML models (not RNN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, if the inputs are filled with zeros to the maximum size, weights in these variables are discarded. This is the same as having inputs with different sizes of variables.